# Possible to share global variable between two functions without a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, global-variables

With the below code, I get

```
{ test1: 'aaa', test2: 'bbb' }
```

which is what I want. Ie. being able to have a global variable between `t2.js` and `t3.js`.

In this PoC is `t3()` only called once, but in the real case, if will be ~100 instances of `t3()` that never ends, because they collect data in an infinite loop. `t2.js` won't need to modify `c`.

**Question**

Is it possible to be the same, but without a third file (`t1.js` in this case)?

**t1.js**

```
module.exports = {};
```

**t2.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let c = require('./t1');
const t3 = require('./t3');

c.test1 = "aaa";
t3();
console.log(c);

app.get('/test.json', (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(c, null, 2));
});    

app.listen(1900, () => {});
```

**t3.js**

```
let c = require('./t1');
module.exports = () => {
  c.test2 = "bbb";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it'd be simple enough to create an object in the entry point, then pass it around:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const t3 = require('./t3');

const records = {
  test1: "aaa",
};
t3(records);
console.log(records);

app.get('/test.json', (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(records, null, 2));
});    

app.listen(1900, () => {});
```

```
module.exports = (records) => {
  records.test2 = "bbb";
};
```

Note that neither in this code, nor in your original code, global variables are being used (except, I suppose, for `require`).

Comment: I don't understand why this works. When you `t3(records)` doesn't `t3` just get a one-off copy of `records`?

Comment: It's not a copy, it's the same object. The top-level code in a module only runs once anyway, no matter when/how it's imported.

Comment: So EcmaScript never makes a copy of the arguments to a function?

Comment: That's right, it doesn't, not really. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language You could think of every identifier (or variable, or parameter) as something that points to a particular structure in memory. Passing an argument passes a link to the structure. Mutating the argument mutates the structure. Reassigning the argument to something else results in no change to the original.

Comment: I would have imagined I would have needed to pass a reference or pointer to the object, as it is done in C/C++.

Comment: Btw. Why doesn't Node give a compile error at `const records`. How it is possible to modify a `const`?

Comment: `const` indicates that the variable will not be reassigned - that the link it points to never changes to some other location. Mutating an object does not change the fact that a variable that points to the object still keeps pointing to that object. The object's contents might be different, but the object remains the same object.